# OpenCv image unstable while running AES decryption

Tags: opencv, openssl, aes

I am trying to capture video from webcam using Opencv and transmit it over TCP. In addition, I wanted to encrypt the video using AES. But whenever run the AES decrpt function the video is unstable.

I am using the [opencv over tcp example](http://nashruddin.com/Streaming_OpenCV_Videos_Over_the_Network) and [AES example](http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36)

Whenever I run this function:

```
img->imageData = aes_decrypt(&de, img->imageData, &imgsize);
```

my video gets unstable.

I have attached the code segment where I wrote the function.

```
/* start receiving images*/

while(1)
{ 

  /* get raw data */
  for (i = 0; i < imgsize; i += bytes) {
    if ((bytes = recv(sock, sockdata + i, imgsize - i, 0)) == -1) {
      quit("recv failed", 1);
    }
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  for (i = 0, k = 0; i < img->height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < img->width; j++) {
      ((uchar*)(img->imageData + i * img->widthStep))[j] = sockdata[k++];
    }
  }

  img->imageData = aes_decrypt(&de, img->imageData, &imgsize); 

  is_data_ready = 1;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  /* have we terminated yet? */
  pthread_testcancel();

  /* no, take a rest for a while */
  usleep(1000);
}
```

This is my first post, sorry for my bad English and format of the post.

Comment: The first thing would be to check that you are getting the same values out of the decryption that you put into the encryption

Comment: Exactly, try to separate out the encryption/decryption and test it against known input.Could you also please indicate what you mean exactly by "unstable"? Do you have stuttering, or incorrect images, wrong colors?

Comment: PS *if* your aes_decrypt only processes local data then it does not need to be protected with a mutex I guess. If not, you might want to rewrite the code in such a way that it does.